# AngularJS: How to use directives to dynamically remove class from all elements with specific ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, removeclass, angularjs-ng-model

The solution I'm trying to attain in a nutshell, is deleting the class `clicked` from every element with a certain class name or `ng-class` name or `ng-model` name, then adding the class name on the button that was clicked.

I have some elements that are repeated using `ng-repeat` throughout the page. They're not in the same areas on the page. Is there anyway that either `$scope` or a directive can remove a class from every element that has that `ng-model` or every child elementon that page?

Directive:

```
app.directive('sibs', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                element.parent().children().removeClass('clicked');
                element.addClass('clicked');
            })
        },
    }
});
```

This code is only applicable to the elements next to/around the element that was clicked. I'm trying to make the removeclass() function apply to all elements with that `ng-model` name on the page.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="a in MyArray" ng-show="isSet(a.ID)">
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID}}" ng-model="myModel" value="1" ng-click="selected(1)" />
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID+1}}" ng-model="myModel" value="2" ng-click="selected(2)" />
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID+2}}" ng-model="myModel" value="3" ng-click="selected(3)" />
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID+3}}" ng-model="myModel" value="4" ng-click="selected(4)" />
    </div>
</div>

<p> There's more code here inbetween these parts </p>

<div>
    <div ng-repeat="a in MyArray" ng-show="isSet(a.ID)">
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID}}" ng-model="myModel" value="1" ng-click="selected(1)" />
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID+1}}" ng-model="myModel" value="2" ng-click="selected(2)" />
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID+2}}" ng-model="myModel" value="3" ng-click="selected(3)" />
        <input sibs type="button" id="{{a.ID+3}}" ng-model="myModel" value="4" ng-click="selected(4)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've switched some elements and values of course, so some values might not make sense as to why they are that value.

Say for example the first `ng-repeat` loops twice and so does the second, if I were to click on any button element on the first loop, then clicked on another button element anywhere else, I want to be able to clear ALL buttons with `ng-model` as `myModel`. Then when all else is cleared from this class, the element that was clicked gets the class added. Is this possible?

Or can I do this with an `ng-click` function?

If this is possible with `ng-class`, can someone please provide a coded solution as to how this is possible?

Comment: First, why is there a `ngModel` => `<div ng-model="outsideModel">`?

Comment: @developer033 There's no reason for this, I can take it out. Put that in last minute to experiment with.

Comment: In a nutshell, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @developer033 I'm looking to remove class `clicked` from all the buttons in the code above if a button is clicked, and adding the `clicked` class to that button alone. If another button anywhere else was clicked after that first click, same thing would happen. I was hoping that this could be done with a directive and `ng-model` but I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: Well.. it seems a little bit strange, you are already inside the `ngRepeat` and also putting 4 buttons for every element... if you have 30 elements, you'll have 120 buttons with the **same** ngModel, which is completely wrong. Also, what's the reason to have `ngModel` in a button?

Comment: @developer033 maybe the way I'm going about it is wrong in terms of labeling each element with the same `ng-model` name, if I could do this with any other way even excluding `ng-model` I would be open to the solution, but currently with the "nutshell what I'm looking to do" solution, I'm a little lost as to how to delete a class from all elements with a certain class name, then adding it only to the one clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation. I think you should look into using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Edit: Kindly try this logic. Haven't got to chance to debug it myself though

```
ng-class="{'clicked': condition(a, $first)}" //a = element from repeat
```

in your js

```
var prevElem;

$scope.condition(element, isFirst){
  var x = prevElem == element;
 if(isFirst $$ prevElem != null)
   x = false;
 if(!x)
   prevElem = element;
 return !x;
}
```

Just add logic to make prevElem to the current element you clicked on your click event.

Comment: If you can provide a little code as to how to accomplish this with the current situation and my given code, I'll give you the answer. I thought about using that approach, but I'm a little lost as to how to proceed.

Comment: Just to clear things out, based on this statement " _if I were to click on any button element on the first loop, then clicked on another button element anywhere else, I want to be able to clear ALL buttons_ " you only want **one** input to contain the _clicked_ class?

Comment: Essentially yes. but I have three other button input groups with different `ng-model` names on the page that I don't want this to effect. So I was hoping that this could happen with only elements with `ng-model` set as `myModel`. but really any solution you have to accomplishing this will suffice.

Comment: I've just tried your solution, but there's one error. Every first element in every `ng-repeat` loop has `clicked` class inserted by default at the very start. So, when the page loads, every first button in every `ng-repeat` has class `clicked`

Comment: Oh, missed that, haha. I think the easiest way to solve that now is to just _add a property_ to the object being iterated to signify that it should/nt have the `clicked` class

Comment: Added a workaround for the issue you mentioned. Hope it helps in case you haven't got it yet. :)